# Show a form in a new window in silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, new-operator, show

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to mimic the "`.show();`" method silverlight 4?

Basically I have a form that includes a button.  When that button is clicked, I would like the program to bring up another form that I have created.  So essentially, in Page1.cs I have:

```
private void btn_Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Page2 np = new Page2();
}
```

In a winForms application programming in C#, I would then add `np.Show();` beneath the codeline `Page2 np = new Page2();` to bring up Page2 in a new window.  However, it won't let me add the `.show();` to `np`.

So I was wondering if there was possibly a Using directive I might be missing somewhere or if anyone knew of a silverlight equivalent to the winforms `.show()` method or even if there is a better way to accomplish the task of opening Page2 on the button click in Page1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could use a `ChildWindow`

Assuming Page is a Control of some type you could

```
ChildWindow popup = new ChildWindow
{
    Title="Page2",
    Content = new Page(),
};

popup.Show();
```

Here's some more information about [ChildWindows](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/29/silverlight-3-s-new-child-windows.aspx),  This will pop up a pseudo window in the browser in a modal mode.

Comment: Yes, this should do the trick.  Thank you, sir, and have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a navigation based framework. So it does not enable you to open multiple windows the way you have done with win forms.